# Custom Navigation Map Controls for Bing Maps (formerly Virtual Earth) to replace the default MS one

Tags: bing-maps, virtual-earth

I'd like to jazz up our map interface which uses microsoft's bing maps.
I'm tired of the default blue control that you see on every page.

I'm not a graphic designer so I was wondering **if anyone had created custom map controls which they wouldn't mind sharing with the community for commercial purposes.**

I really like the one that harley-davidson developed here:
http://rideplanner.harley-davidson.com/rideplanner/ridePlanner.jsp?locale=en_US

[image: Harley Davidson Map Control As of June 30, 2009]
<sub>(source: [blakerobertson.com](http://www.blakerobertson.com/storage/perm/hd_mapcontrol.png))</sub>

Edit 1: Still am interested.
Edit 2: Still interested...

Comment: I think the DeepEarth project has a control that you can use inside your project. I'm not quite sure about licensing but I'm sure there are things that can be done with it. See: http://deepearth.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript simple hide the default navigation controls using map options. Then overlay a div on top of the map using absolute positioning and create your custom navigation controls in there. The jQuery UI slider can be used as a zoom slider.

If you are using one of the other Bing Maps controls such as Silverlight, WPF or Windows 8, a similar process can be done by hiding the default controls and create custom ones in XAML.